# функция неправильно принимает аргумент типа long/unsigned int

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long long func(n)
{
    long long x = abs(n);
}

int main()
{

    const short         a = -(0x5B4);
    const int           b = -(0x54292E64);
    const unsigned int  c = 0x8312E9EE;
    const long          d = 0x3D90FE;
    const unsigned long e = 0xC777CD3A;

    func(a);
    func(b);
    func(c);
    func(d);
    func(e);
    return 0;
}
```

Переменна `c`, равная `0x8312E9EE` == `2199054830`, поступает в функцию `func()` как `-2095912466`.

Tо же самое происходит с `d`/`e`.

Comment: Если вы не указали тип для аргумента функции, то по умолчанию используется `int` (по крайней мере мне об этом заявил мой GCC), а дальше вполне логично, что `unsigned int` и `unsigned long` в него не влезают

Comment: @andreymal поставил (long long n), для unsigned int/unsigned long все равно не работает

Comment: Тогда поехали дальше — а как вы проверяете, что как куда поступает? В показанном вами коде нет никакого вывода или чего-то подобного

Comment: У вас аргументы 5 разных типов, соответственно вам необходимо написать 5 разных функций. И еще учесть, что библиотечная функция `abs` существует только для одного из них, а в четырех остальных случаях придется использовать что-то еще.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте компилятор чтобы контролировать работу с данными в C.

Компилируем:

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.c
> temp.c: In function ‘func’:
> temp.c:6:11: error: type of ‘n’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Werror=implicit-int]
>     6 | long long func(n)
>       |           ^~~~
> temp.c:8:15: error: unused variable ‘x’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
>     8 |     long long x = abs(n);
>       |               ^
> temp.c:9:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
>     9 | }
>       | ^
> cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
> ```

Три ошибки: не указан тип параметра `n`, не использована `x`, нет возврата значения из `func`. Две последние поправить не сложно: добавим `return x;`. Первую поправим как компилятор предлагает: установим тип `int` параметру `n`:

```
long long func(int n)
{
    long long x = abs(n);
    return x;
}
```

Компилируем:

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.c
> temp.c: In function ‘main’:
> temp.c:23:10: error: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘unsigned int’ may change the sign of the result [-Werror=sign-conversion]
>    23 |     func(c);
>       |          ^
> temp.c:24:10: error: conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘int’ may change value [-Werror=conversion]
>    24 |     func(d);
>       |          ^
> temp.c:25:10: error: conversion from ‘long unsigned int’ to ‘int’ may change value [-Werror=conversion]
>    25 |     func(e);
>       |          ^
> cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
> ```

Другие три ошибки и все связаны с неявными приведениями. Ясно что мы поспешили писать `int n`, надо что-нибудь пошире, скажем `long long n` - это самый широкий тип со знаком.

Компилируем:

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.c
> temp.c: In function ‘func’:
> temp.c:8:19: error: absolute value function ‘abs’ given an argument of type ‘long long int’ but has parameter of type ‘int’ which may cause truncation of value [-Werror=absolute-value]
>     8 |     long long x = abs(n);
>       |                   ^~~
> temp.c:8:23: error: conversion from ‘long long int’ to ‘int’ may change value [-Werror=conversion]
>     8 |     long long x = abs(n);
>       |                       ^
> temp.c: In function ‘main’:
> temp.c:25:10: error: conversion to ‘long long int’ from ‘long unsigned int’ may change the sign of the result [-Werror=sign-conversion]
>    25 |     func(e);
>       |          ^
> cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
> ```

Опять три ошибки! Что ты будешь делать? Первые две о том что `abs` не умеет работать с `long long`. Находим `llabs` в [документации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs).

Последняя ошибка про запрет неявно приводить `long unsigned` к `long long`. Потому что эти два типа могут быть одного размера и приведение будет терять данные. Добавляем явное приведение: `func((long long)e);`.

Окончательный рабочий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long long func(long long n)
{
    long long x = llabs(n);
    return x;
}

int main()
{

    const short         a = -(0x5B4);
    const int           b = -(0x54292E64);
    const unsigned int  c = 0x8312E9EE;
    const long          d = 0x3D90FE;
    const unsigned long e = 0xC777CD3A;

    func(a);
    func(b);
    func(c);
    func(d);
    func((long long)e);
    return 0;
}
```

Компилируем:

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.c
> ```

Компилятор доволен - в коде нет никаких ошибок.

Comment: [Не думаю что сейчас можно отыскать столь странную конфигурацию](https://godbolt.org/z/s5Y3xMqj4)...

Comment: @wololo, как всегда точно и по делу. Поправил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе не надо удивляться, когда тип параметра в определении функции не согласен с типом аргумента при ее вызове, тем более, когда для аргумента нет в параметре достаточного количества байтов.

Я изменил вашу функцию, чтобы она вывела какую-то информацию.

Сначала так

```
void func(int n)
{
    long long x = abs(n);
    cout << "Input:  " << hex << "0x" << n << dec << " (" << n << ")" << endl;
    cout << "Output: " << hex << "0x" << x << dec << " (" << x << ")" << endl;
}
```

и затем вместо вашего (стандартного) параметра `int n` применил `long n`:

```
void func(long n)
{
    long long x = abs(n);
    cout << "Input:  " << hex << "0x" << n << dec << " (" << n << ")" << endl;
    cout << "Output: " << hex << "0x" << x << dec << " (" << x << ")" << endl;
}
```

Т.к. для первых двух переменных `a` и `b` для вас все в порядке, я вызвал эту функцию только для переменных `c`, `d`, и `е`:

```
    func(c);
    func(d);
    func(e);
```

и результаты для сравнения я ввел в таблицу:

| ваш аргумент / результат | void func(int n) | void func(long n) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **unsigned** int c = `0x8312E9EE;` | `Input: 0x8312e9ee (-2095912466)` | `Input: 0x8312e9ee (2199054830)` |
| **abs(c)** | `Output: 0x7ced1612 (2095912466)` | `Output: 0x8312e9ee (2199054830)` |
| long d = `0x3D90FE;` | `Input: 0x3d90fe (4034814)` | `Input: 0x3d90fe (4034814)` |
| **abs(d)** | `Output: 0x3d90fe (4034814)` | `Output: 0x3d90fe (4034814)` |
| **unsigned** long e = `0xC777CD3A;` | `Input: 0xc777cd3a (-948449990)` | `Input: 0xc777cd3a (3346517306)` |
| **abs(e)** | `Output: 0x388832c6 (948449990)` | `Output: 0xc777cd3a (3346517306)` |

Из минусовых десятичных изображений (в скобках) вы можете видеть, что проблема проявляется **только для больших `unsigned` значений и только в случае определения параметра `n` как `int`**

Почему?

1. Определение `int n` - это неявно то же самое, как **`signed`** `int n`, значит, *верхняя* половина возможных бинарных чисел (дана количеством байтов) интерпретируется как *отрицательные*.
2. Чем больший размер для параметра (напр. `long` вместо `int`) тем больший шанс, что переданный ему аргумент попадет в *книжную* половину диапазона всех возможных бинарных чисел и тем самым *не будет интерпретирован как отрицательное число.*
3. Почему ваше большое число `c = 0x8312E9EE` (десятично 2199054830) интерпретируется не как -2199054830, а как -2095912466?

   Потому что вычисляется оно так для 32-битогого `int`:

   ```
    4294967296   // pow(2,32) == pow(16, 8), т.е. 16*16*16*16*16*16*16*16
   -2199054830
   -----------
    2095912466
   ```

   или в шестнадцатеричном то же самое

   ```
     100000000
    - 8312E9EE
    ----------
      7CED1612
   ```

Comment: Не учтено, что в языке C функция `abs` имеет параметр типа `int`. Следовательно, например, для `Input: 3346517306` [результатом будет](https://godbolt.org/z/4KzKKbq4W) `948449990` (При условии, что тип `int` — обычный 32-битный). В C++ же есть перегруженные версии, принимающие `long` и `long long`.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вам с вашими запросами поможет разве что только С++ с его

```
template<integral T>
unsigned long long func(T n)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) <= sizeof(unsigned long long));
    if constexpr (is_signed_v<T>)
        return n < 0 ? -n : n;
    else
        return n;
}
```

:)